# Doesnt choose first option in form - select without changing to to another option and then change back

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this form. When the page is displayed is seems that the first option is choosen, but when I then submit nothing happend. If I change to option two or three and then back to option one then the page redirect when I push submit.

Any suggestion how to fix this small "bug"

```
<form method="post" action=javascript:action; >
<select class="price" onChange="this.form.action=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option selected="selected" value="cart.php?a=add&pid=72">Kr. 999.00,- årlig</option>
<option value="cart.php?a=add&pid=73">Kr. 999.00,- toårig</option>
<option value="cart.php?a=add&pid=74">Kr. 999.00,- treårig</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Bestill" class="buy-now" />
```

Now I have this code shown under, but it doesnt redirect to the new cart.php page.

Here is the complete code, and jquery is loaded in header file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cmbPrice").change(function(){
fnChangeFormAction();
});
fnChangeFormAction();
});
function fnChangeFormAction(){
var action = $("#cmbPrice").val();
$("#frmMyForm").attr("action", action);
}
</script>

<form method="post" name="frmMyForm" id="frmMyForm" action='' >
<select class="price" name="cmbPrice" id="cmbPrice">
<option selected="selected" value="cart.php?a=add&amp;pid=72">Kr. 700.00,- årlig</option>
<option value="cart.php?a=add&amp;pid=73">Kr. 1400.00,- toårig</option>
<option value="cart.php?a=add&amp;pid=74">Kr. 1800.00,- treårig</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Bestill" class="buy-now" />
```

Comment: you have to set the form action for the first time when the page loads.  
you can do it by using the `onload` method of the body.

Comment: Could you please give me info where this onload should be done? I tried to have it a onload function in the body section but cant really get it to work out, or maybe Im doing it wrong.

Comment: Are you using `jquery` or pure `javascript`?

Comment: On this I use javascript, but could also use jquery since I have that allready loaded in header of my page, and use it for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, since you want to use `jquery` I assume that you have included the `jquery` library. if not, you can add this line in you "head" section and use the latest version of `jquery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

you can use the `googleapis` hosted version of `jquery` or you can host it on your own site(which is not recommended)

in your head section add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cmbPrice").change(function(){
    fnChangeFormAction();
  });

  fnChangeFormAction();
});


function fnChangeFormAction(){
  var action = $("#cmbPrice").val();
  $("#frmMyForm").attr("action", action);
}
</script>
```

and then change your `form` like this:

```
<form method="post" name="frmMyForm" id="frmMyForm" action="">
<select class="price" name="cmbPrice" id="cmbPrice">
<option selected="selected" value="cart.php?a=add&pid=72">Kr. 999.00,- årlig</option>
<option value="cart.php?a=add&pid=73">Kr. 999.00,- toårig</option>
<option value="cart.php?a=add&pid=74">Kr. 999.00,- treårig</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Bestill" class="buy-now" />
</form>
```

that's it...

---

### Updated - The simple complete code...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cmbPrice").change(function(){
    fnChangeFormAction();
    });

    fnChangeFormAction();
  });

  function fnChangeFormAction(){
    var action = $("#cmbPrice").val();
    $("#frmMyForm").attr("action", action);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" name="frmMyForm" id="frmMyForm" action='' >
<select class="price" name="cmbPrice" id="cmbPrice">
<option selected="selected" value="cart.php?a=add&amp;pid=72">Kr. 700.00,- årlig</option>
<option value="cart.php?a=add&amp;pid=73">Kr. 1400.00,- toårig</option>
<option value="cart.php?a=add&amp;pid=74">Kr. 1800.00,- treårig</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Bestill" class="buy-now" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but now it doesnt redirect to cart.php pages after clicking submit button

Comment: Can you please post your complete code here? (update you original question)

Comment: I updated my post, with the code I have now, per your suggestion of solution.

Comment: The code is working fine if you have included the `jquery` library and also not to forget to close the form tag "</form>".  
I'll update my answer with a simple complete code...